# If I shallow merge two identical objects which object's references are used?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let obj1 = {a: [1, 2]};
let obj2 = {a: [1, 2]};
Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
```

The resulting object will be: `{a: [1, 2]}`. However, will the array `[1, 2]` refer to the array in obj1's memory or obj2's memory?

Comment: seems like an easy thing to test. obj1.a.push("3") obj2.a.push("4")

Comment: `obj2.a` ......

Answer (score 2):

You can start by reading the documentation for `Object.assign()`: [Merging objects with same properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Merging_objects_with_same_properties).

Then you can verify with [strict equals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity):

```
let obj1 = {a: [1, 2]};
let obj2 = {a: [1, 2]};
let merge = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
obj1.a === merge.a; // false
obj2.a === merge.a; // true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const obj3 = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
```

`obj3.a` will refer to `obj2.a`. From [`Object.assign` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Description)

> Properties in the target object will be overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key.

Most importantly,

> Later sources' properties will similarly overwrite earlier ones.